# Serialization of python (django) data to javascript

Tags: python, django, json, simplejson, dajax

I'm trying to return data to javascript using json.dumps in order to show data to the user.

Dajax call when button is pressed:
`Dajaxice.chamber.ATableUpdate(TableUpdate);`

My ajax function:

```
@dajaxice_register
def ATableUpdate(request):
    mean = [[900, 2.1],[1000, -20.4],[1100, -15.4],[1200, -30.5]]
    numpy.savetxt("table_mean.txt", mean)
    mean2 = numpy.loadtxt("table_mean.txt")
    return json.dumps({"mean": mean})
```

If I return the value mean as shown, it all works, but if instead I return mean2 (the same values read from a file with numpy) it does not work, and gives the error: "Is not JSON serializable"

The code is simply to pull data from file and show the data to the user in a table. 
The file is updated with values from sensors connected to the system.

Any ideas on how to serialize my numpy data? Or how to return an array to my html without using javascript and only using djangos template?

HTML class to print table in

```
<div class="box_result_inner">
<table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="1px" border="1px" id="tablehtml">
</table>  
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function TableUpdate(data){
    var col=data.mean[0].length;
    var row=data.mean.length;
    buffer='';
    for(var r = 0; r < row; r++){
        buffer += "<tr>";
        for(var c = 0; c < col ; c++){
            buffer += "<td>" + data.mean[r][c] + "</td>";
        }
        buffer += "</tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("tablehtml").innerHTML = buffer;
 }
```

**Update**
Unfortunately *list* didn't work for me as it added *array* in front of every row, however, got it working with:

```
with open("chamber/control/data/table_mean.txt", 'wb') as fp:
    json.dump(mean, fp)

with open("chamber/control/data/table_mean.txt", 'rb') as fp:
    mean2 = json.load(fp)

return json.dumps({"mean": mean2})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python JSON module can only handle certain native Python types listed [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders).

The [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) function returns an `array` type and so is not serializable.

Instead, convert the `array` to a `list`, then convert to JSON:

```
mean2 = list(numpy.loadtxt("table_mean.txt"))
return json.dumps({"mean": mean})
```

This operation may be expensive depending on the size of the `numpy` array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But still gets an error using list. When trying to print mean2 "array" is printed in front of every row: array([900, 2.1]), array([1000, -20.4]).
However, got it working by writing and reading differently from the file.

Comment: @madsendennes You didn't show the input format of your data, but it appears as though you have an array of arrays.  So, you have to convert each array to a list type.  The premise of the answer remains; types have to be converted to those supported by JSON serializer as listed in the link before serialization.